# How do you define a macro in ARMv8?

Tags: gnu-assembler, arm64

I'm new to assembly language coding and I have not been able to find any answers to this question of the web. I'm not sure if I'm even asking the right question but I thought it couldn't hurt. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The examples below assume one is using 
[GNU AS compiler](http://www.coranac.com/files/gba/re-ejected-gasref.pdf).

Macros are neat and I use them a lot; however, they can be a pain to debug so be careful. If you are new to Assembly, I would suggest learning ARMv7 first since there are many more books, tutorials, etc. than ARMv8.

```
// push2
.macro push2, xreg1, xreg2
.push2\@:
        stp     \xreg1, \xreg2, [sp, #-16]!
.endm

// pop2
.macro  pop2, xreg1, xreg2
.pop2\@:
        ldp     \xreg1, \xreg2, [sp], #16
.endm


// exit
    .macro _exit
    .exit\@:
            mov x8, #93             // exit see /usr/include/asm-generic/unistd.h
            svc 0
    .endm

.macro gCode num                // Grey code...  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code
.gCode\@:
        mov x0, \num
        eor x0, x0, x0, lsr 1   // G Code == B XOR (B >> 1 unsigned)
.endm
```